# Facebook birthdays are appearing in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am receiving Facebook birthday reminders all of a sudden.  I don't see the actual birthdays anywhere in my calendar.  I searched and used list view and everything else I can find from Googling.  Yet every so often I will get a reminder 15 hours in advance of someones birthday.

Where are these coming from?  They do not appear in my home computer or laptop.  They just appear in my office Outlook 2016 client.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook automatically generates Birthday reminders for the contacts you create with Birthday information.

According to my research, we can filter Birthday items and then delete all. Please refer to steps:
[How To Remove All Birthday Reminders In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2184-outlook-remove-all-birthday-reminders.html)

Comment: I don't have that many contacts, the ones that are popping up are only facebook contacts, never communicate them through my Office account.  Even before filtering there were no birthdays listed.  When I did as instructed, zero birthdays were returned, hence the confusion I am having.

Comment: Have you subscribed to your Facebook calendar?

Comment: I don’t believe I have.  I have more Facebook birthdays mentioned on Facebook than what’s mentioned in outlook.  I think years ago I tried importing birthdays but stupidly imported everyone. I thought I deleted them but I still get notified even though I don’t see any evidence of them existing now.  Which doesn’t make sense because it has to be coming from some place.

Comment: If reminders still appear after events were deleted, we can try running /cleanreminders which will helps clear and regenerate reminders.Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /cleanreminders and then press Enter.

Comment: I had tried that already to no affect